# Importing RxJS using named imports or 'add' string

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Whats the difference between importing RxJS functions and methods using only a string and importing using a named import. For example:

Using the 'add' string:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Using a named import

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge'
```

An individual method only works one way but I can't work out how to tell which way a particular method needs to be imported. Is there a way to determine which method to use, and what's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first import will patch the Observable prototype with the map method so it will be available on all instances of this type.

The second one is importing just a function that can be called with some arguments and will return an Observable.

Patching the prototype does not work well with things like tree shaking so in the latest versions of RxJs the pipe method was added and all the imports are named.

Example from [RxJs readme](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs):

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200)
  .pipe(filter(x => x % 2 === 1), map(x => x + x))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this makes any difference since explicitly using an import precludes tree-shaking by definition.

Comment: @AluanHaddad there are several benefits to the new pipeable operatos. They are stated in the 'Why' section of [the docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

Comment: I've read that before. I think the change is more about fashion than anything else to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

The operators under `rxjs/observable` namespace are known as [pipepable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) operators.

This is preferable over the old patch operators under `rxjs/add`. Because patching the Observable.prototype makes it impossible to be tree-shaken by bundlers. Among other reasons.